# Can an international student in Canada apply for conjugal visa for girlfriend?

Tags: visas, canada, study

My boyfriend has just become an international student in Canada. We are are trying to find the best way for me to reach him and work over there. I am Italian, so one option is the Working Holiday visa, but it will allow me to work only for 6 months. 
We are not married, so we can not apply for spouse visa, and we do not fall into the common-law partnership category, as we have not been living together for 1 straight year. 
We were thinking of the conjugal partenr visa, but the regulation on that is not very clear. 
Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: [That visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5289ETOC.asp) requires a sponsor who's a Canadian citizen, Registered Indian (aka First Peoples), or a permanent resident. Your boyfriend doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: Your question is also attracting close votes because you're looking for a long-term visa. This question is a better fit on Expatriates.